# ASP.NET MVC Razor and css block

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want some flexibility in my css style block so i decide to inject some server side code, f.e.

```
#defaultGameContainer {
            position: relative;
            width: @(SiteConfig.Instance.Game.Width + "px");
            height: 600px;
            top: 100px;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -480px;
        }
```

But it seems not work, i have a error in VS like 'unexpected characters sequence...'
Are we restricted to use Razor syntax in css?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use LESS Css for .NET `http://www.dotlesscss.org/`

Comment: Thank you for response. I think it is little overhead to linking entire library to achieve so simple task, because i have only simple css block that not intended to grow later.

Comment: @igorGIS humm.. then you can use ajax to retrive "SiteConfig.Instance.Game.Width" and assign it using jquery to your #defaultGameContainer: $("#defaultGameContainer").css("width", ajaxResult)

Comment: Sounds like a solution. Very strange, as i remember we can use <%= %> syntax in asp.net 4 in any part of page, including css bloks. Why we can't in MVC

Comment: because CSS are not registered type to MVC's Razor engine, only cshtml are recognized. So you can only put css block into <style> tag within a cshtml page, this can work. But seperate .css file won't be processed by razor.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can add a custom `CSS` block for a specific `.cshtml` View by following these instructions:

First off, Define in the `.cshtml` view your custom CSS block

```
@section CustomCSS{ 
<style>
    #floorsList > tbody > tr > td {
        vertical-align: middle
    }
</style>
}
```

Then, you need to embed this **CustomCSS** *section* in `_layout.cshtml` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Your Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)
    <!--Consider the following line -->
    @RenderSection("CustomCSS", required: false)
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is limited to layouts

Answer (score 3):

css/js files are not parsed by mvc razor views engine

you can create CssController (be sure you don't have Css folder in project directory) which returns plain text

controller:

```
public class CssController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 6000, VaryByParam = "l")]
    public ActionResult generatecss()
    {
        return View("generatecss");
    }
}
```

view: generatecss.cshtml

```
@{ Layout = ""; }
#defaultGameContainer {
        position: relative;
        width: @(SiteConfig.Instance.Game.Width + "px");
        height: 600px;
        top: 100px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -480px;
    }
```

put it in layout as stylesheet

```
<link href="~/Css/generatecss" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Hi your need to return the correct type/mime type in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys! All you suggest is just fine! 
And at the end of experimenting i found that it works even with those annoying VS warnings. 
So we can just mix c# with css just in `<style>...</style>` block in main `_layout.cshtml` and ingore those warnings.